# Duplicate records while retrieving using inner join in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am facing issues as I get records from SQL. The output of records was not right and numbers returned are much bigger than what I expected it to be.

Here is my query:

```
var query= 
$@"select CAST(CustomerAssignedTaskExec.ScheduledDispatchedDateTime as DATE) as 'Date', 
CustomerTaskDetails.CustomerTaskTypeId, COUNT(*) as 'Count' from CustomerAssignedTaskExec
inner join CustomerAssignedTask on CustomerAssignedTask.Id = CustomerAssignedTaskExec.CustomerAssignedTaskId
inner join CustomerTaskDetails on CustomerTaskDetails.Id = CustomerAssignedTaskExec.CustomerTaskDetailsId
inner join CustomerAssignedTaskItemStatus on CustomerAssignedTaskItemStatus.Id =
CustomerAssignedTaskExec.AssignedTaskItemStatusId
inner join customers on customers.CustomerId = CustomerAssignedTask.CustomerId
where Customers.StoreId = @storeId and CustomerAssignedTask.TaskStatusId = @runningTaskStatusId
group by CAST(CustomerAssignedTaskExec.ScheduledDispatchedDateTime AS DATE),
CustomerTaskTypeId, CustomerAssignedTaskItemStatus.Id";
```

This is my expected result :

```
Count    CustomerTaskTypeId   ScheduledDispatchedDateTime
852           7                    2019-08-20
```

but what I get is :

```
Count    CustomerTaskTypeId   ScheduledDispatchedDateTime   
4694           7                    2019-08-20


What are the reasons why this is happening? Thank you for the help.
```

Comment: You must be ignoring few more join conditions. Without actually knowing the table structure we can't help you more.

Comment: first thing which DBMS you are using `mysql`, `sqlserver`, `postgresql` ...etc. also table structure schema is needed with sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `count(distinct <value>)` instead of `count(*)` maybe that could help as there might be other columns associated leading to redundant data

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. You may use `1` instead of `*`, it will count only the distinct rows created by your `group by` clause.

```
var query= $@"select CAST(CustomerAssignedTaskExec.ScheduledDispatchedDateTime as DATE) as 'Date',
                        CustomerTaskDetails.CustomerTaskTypeId, COUNT(1) as 'Count'
                        from CustomerAssignedTaskExec
                            inner join CustomerAssignedTask on CustomerAssignedTask.Id = CustomerAssignedTaskExec.CustomerAssignedTaskId
                            inner join CustomerTaskDetails on CustomerTaskDetails.Id = CustomerAssignedTaskExec.CustomerTaskDetailsId
                            inner join CustomerAssignedTaskItemStatus on CustomerAssignedTaskItemStatus.Id = CustomerAssignedTaskExec.AssignedTaskItemStatusId
                            inner join customers on customers.CustomerId = CustomerAssignedTask.CustomerId
                            where Customers.StoreId = @storeId and CustomerAssignedTask.TaskStatusId = @runningTaskStatusId
                            group by CAST(CustomerAssignedTaskExec.ScheduledDispatchedDateTime AS DATE), CustomerTaskTypeId, CustomerAssignedTaskItemStatus.Id";
```

Comment: What is the difference between Count(*) and Count(1) ?

Answer (score 0):

try remove your `CustomerAssignedTaskItemStatus.Id` and `CustomerTaskTypeId` in your grouping and give me the results.

```
select CAST(CustomerAssignedTaskExec.ScheduledDispatchedDateTime as DATE) as 'Date',
                        COUNT(1) as 'Count'
                        from CustomerAssignedTaskExec
                            inner join CustomerAssignedTask on CustomerAssignedTask.Id = CustomerAssignedTaskExec.CustomerAssignedTaskId
                            inner join CustomerTaskDetails on CustomerTaskDetails.Id = CustomerAssignedTaskExec.CustomerTaskDetailsId
                            inner join CustomerAssignedTaskItemStatus on CustomerAssignedTaskItemStatus.Id = CustomerAssignedTaskExec.AssignedTaskItemStatusId
                            inner join customers on customers.CustomerId = CustomerAssignedTask.CustomerId
                            where Customers.StoreId = @storeId and CustomerAssignedTask.TaskStatusId = @runningTaskStatusId
                            group by CAST(CustomerAssignedTaskExec.ScheduledDispatchedDateTime AS DATE)
```

Comment: still the same result.